Pasar Array de datos en JSON a JavaScript <a onclick
Muy buenas,
Intento pasar un array de datos en formato JSON desde PHP a una función JavaScript mediante un enlace HTML:
echo '<a href="#" onclick=PDFComplejo('. json_encode($filas).')"> cumplen los requisitos de la carta de servicios.</a>';

El array proviene de una consulta a MySQL:
$filas=mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mensajes where (fecentrada >= '$fec1') and (fecentrada <= '$fec2')"));

He comprobado que el array se llena y se convierte bien a JSON:
[["252","1","sef","","uncorreo@correo.es","2024-02-02","2024-02-02","2024-09-06","0000-00-00","0","","","0"],["253","1","dsfsfad","","uncorreo@correo.es","2024-02-02","2024-02-02","2024-09-06","0000-00-00","0","","","0"]
...


La función JavaScript sirve para crear un pdf con la librería jsPDF y autotable:
function PDFComplejo(rows){
        
        var pdf = new jsPDF("L","mm","A4"); //orientacion, medida a usar, tamaño
         
        var columns = ["Id","Unidad","Pregunta","Respuesta","email"];
        
        var data = rows;
        
        pdf.autoTable( columns,data,{
...


Cuando pulso el enlace se me arroja el siguiente error y ya he probado de todo:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at VM7601 estadisticas.php:1:15)
y en la consola puedo ver que proviene de la llamada a la función JavaScript. Esto es lo que me muestra al pulsar el error en la consola:
PDFComplejo([[
En las herramientas de desarrollador veo como la función coge el JSON bien, excepto por que le añade un espacio al principio que no se si será valido [[" 252":
<a href="#" onclick=PDFComplejo([[" 252","1","sef","","","2024-02-02","2024-02-02","2024-09-06","0000-00-00","0","","","0"],["253","1","dsfsfad","","","2024-02-02","2024-02-02","2024-09-06","0000-00-00","0","","","0"],["254","1","dsfsfad","","","2024-02-02","2024-02-02","2024-09-06","0000-00-00","0","","","0"],["255","1","dsfsfad","","","2024-02-
...

Alguna ayuda?
Me estoy partiendo la cabeza.
Gracias

No entiendo por qué metes código PHP en un contexto de Javascript. Considera que PHP trabaja de lado del servidor y Javascript de lado del cliente y que no es una buena práctica mezclar código de uno en otro. ¿Por qué no devuelves directamente el resultado de la consulta. Por ejemplo: echo json_encode($filas); y luego en Javascript generas el PDF con esos datos? O bien, desde el servidor puedes generar el PDF y ofrecerlo al cliente, en modo de descarga o apertura. Y si hace falta una comunicación constante entre cliente / servidor, usa Ajax o la API Fetch.

Me acabo de dar cuenta de que lo que hace es pararse cuando encuentra un espacio en blanco. He quitado el espacio que había antes de json_encode:
echo '<a href="#" onclick=PDFComplejo('.json_encode($filas).')"> cumplen los requisitos de la carta de servicios.</a>';

y ahora se para en el primer espacio en blanco que encuentra;
PDFComplejo([["252","1","sef","","","2024-02-02","2024-02-02","2024-09-06","0000-00-00","0","","","0"],["258","1","dsfsfad

Para el que le sirva. Quizás es un poco chapuza, pero funciona:
PHP
echo '<a href="#" onclick=PDFComplejo('.str_replace(" ","%20",json_encode($filas,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)).',"Prueba","'.trim("./imagenes/escudo1.jpg").'")> cumplen los requisitos de la carta de servicios.</a>';

JavaScript
function PDFComplejo(rows,nombre_informe,imagen){
        
        rows=(JSON.stringify(rows)).replaceAll("%20"," ");
        rows= JSON.parse(rows);

